# Hola, tengo un problema en el juego del ahorcado en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Bueno tengo el juego y no se como hacer que en las variables (`tupalabra` y `palabra`)  me escoja la lista que he creado de palabras aleatorias para así poder empezar a jugar. Porque las tengo vacías y me marca que ya he ganado directamente y no encuentro forma...
Eso es lo que tengo y ya no sé como afrontarlo..

```
import time
nombre=input("¿Como te llamas? ")
print(" ")
print("hola, "+nombre," Es hora de jugar al ahorcado pequeño bolon")
print (" ") 
print("hola, ",    nombre, " Es hora de jugar al ahorcado pequeño bolon")
print("\n", "\n", "\n", "\n")


time.sleep(1)
print("Comienza a adivinar ")
time.sleep(0.5)
tupalabra=''
palabra=''
vidas=5

import random

with open('archisofi.txt', 'r') as d:
    lineas = [linea.split() for linea in d]

for linea in lineas:
    print(linea)

print(random.choice(linea))



while vidas > 0:

    fallas=0
    for letra in palabra:
        if letra in tupalabra:
            print(letra,end="")
        else:
            print("*",end="")
            fallas+=1
    if fallas==0:
        print("")
        print("Felicidadades ganaste, buen trabajo")
        break

    tuletra=input("Introduce una letra: ")
    tupalabra+=tuletra

    if tuletra not in palabra:
         vidas-=1
         print("Equivocacion")
         print("Tu tienes ",+vidas," vidas")
    if vidas == 0:
         print("Perdiste!")

else:
    print("Gracias por participar")
```

Comment: Este programa tiene un parecido con [este otro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/167169/ayuda-c%c3%b3digo-python-juego-del-ahorcado) ¿Hay alguna relación entre ellos?

Comment: Respondiendo a tu pregunta, no veo que asignes en ningún lugar la variable  `palabra`, salvo al inicio donde le pones la cadena vacía. Entiendo que el `print(random.choice(linea))` debería asignarlo en lugar de imprimirlo, aunque tampoco tengo claro qué sacará ese `random.choice()` pues lo aplicas a `linea`, en lugar de `lineas`. También, sin saber qué contiene el archivo "archisofi.txt" no puedo decirte si lo estás leyendo bien, pero me extraña que construyas una lista de listas (que es lo que produce `linea.split()`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si cada línea del fichero tiene varias palabras, y el archivo tiene varias líneas, necesitas leerlo todo en una sola lista en la que cada elemento sea una palabra. Leerlo en una lista en la que cada elemento sea otra lista, como tú lo haces, complica innecesariamente el problema.

Una forma sencilla de hacer lo que digo es leer el fichero completo en una sola cadena y partirla en trozos por los "blancos" (que no son sólo los espacios en blanco, sino también los retornos de carro, tabuladores, etc.) Así:

```
with open('archisofi.txt', 'r') as d:
    lista_palabras = d.read().split()
```

Una vez todas las palabras están en una lista "plana" (opuesto a "anidada"), la elección de una palabra es sencilla:

```
palabra = random.choice(lista_palabras)
```